# webBrowser2 is not supported anymore to open youtube and others sites

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

i am using this soruce code [webBroswer2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3365/Embed-an-HTML-control-in-your-own-window-using-pla) to display the content of pages in c++ winform but when i try to run site ex: youtube i get message saying

> Your browser is out of date !
> [Your browser is out of date!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3K9F.png)

so how i can make it support open sites like this ? is there a new version of webBrowser2 ?

btw i am using visual studio vb 6.0 c++

hope someone can help me , thank you

Comment: I think this [Introduction to Microsoft Edge WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/)  _"...The Microsoft Edge WebView2 control allows you to embed web technologies (HTML, CSS, and JavaScript) in your native apps. The WebView2 control uses Microsoft Edge as the rendering engine to display the web content in native apps...."_

Comment: In addition `studio vb 6.0 c++` is 20 year old, consider updating to Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition (it's a free download from MS).

Comment: i know i can use WebView2 for C# but for studio vb 6.0 c++ i can not or maybe i do not know how , also i do not know how to upgrade my app to 2022 .. it is old code .

Comment: The `webBrowser2` control hosts MS Internet Explorer, which MS replaced with Edge in 2015.  Since about 2020 sites have stop supporting Internet Explorer (and all it's peculiarities) and therefore `webBrowser2` is probably redundant.

Comment: i can not replace Internet Explorer to Edge in the source code of it ?  , i even found out this https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/800585/Embedded-WebBrowser-IWebBrowser-in-Pure-Cplusplus but still have same problem -.- , is there a new way to display browser contents in c++ like webBrowser2 do ?